# How do I get the keyboard to pop up on mobile browser when using Javascript / JQuery focus() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, setfocus

I am able to use **$('#text-box').focus();** to successfully focus the cursor on the text-box after a page loads. However, when I load the page on a mobile browser the text-box focuses but the keyboard doesn't popup. I tried using click(); but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any idea **how could I make the keyboard popup after text-box focus?** or maybe you know how to achieve this with a different approach? This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    selectTextBox();
});
 
function selectTextBox() {
    $('#tbFirstName_TextBox').focus();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="tbFN">
      <input type="text" id="tbFirstName_TextBox" placeholder="First Name">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: On which mobile platform you're trying?

Comment: Did you try the autofocus attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#autofocus

Comment: I tried iphone safari and mobile chrome. My goal is for it to be functional with most of the mobile web browsers out there.

Comment: I did try the autofocus attribute but no results.